# Retrieve Array of Values from Java Bean in JSP Page

Tags: arrays, jsp, model-view-controller, javabeans

Not able call getNames() from Bean in JSP Page...Successfully Able to set Names, But when i call getNames it Returns  Null

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException, IOException {
  response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

  try {
    List<String> name=new ArrayList<String>();
    name.add("Pushkar");
    name.add("Raj");
    ArrayBean bean=new ArrayBean();
    bean.setNames(name.toArray(new String[name.size()]));       

    // request.getRequestDispatcher("DDL.jsp").forward(request, response);
    response.sendRedirect("DDL.jsp");

  } finally {            
    out.close();
  }

public class ArrayBean {
  public String[] names;

  public String[] getNames() {
    return names;
  }

  public void setNames(String[] names) {
    this.names = names;
  }
}
```

Comment: Show your JSP as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your try catch to

```
try {
name=new ArrayList<String>();
name.add("Pushkar");
name.add("Raj");
ArrayBean bean=new ArrayBean();
bean.names=new String[name.size()];
        bean.names=name.toArray(bean.names);      

// request.getRequestDispatcher("DDL.jsp").forward(request, response);
response.sendRedirect("DDL.jsp");} finally {            
out.close();  }
```

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This Thing Works, I added a LoadData() method in Bean which Sets Values & then i call getNames() from JSP, it works Fine, Removed all the Code from Servlet,Even Servlet is not need now

```
public class ArrayBean {
public List<String> names;

public List<String> getNames() {
    if(names==null){loadNames();
    }return names;
}   


private void loadNames()
{
     names=new ArrayList<String>();
        names.add("Pushkar");
        names.add("Raj");        

}
```

}